# Удаление столбцов и строчек при клике

Tags: javascript

Создается таблица со случайными цветами ячеек.
При клике на [i,j] ячейку нужно удалить(не перекрасить в белый) i-строку,j-столбец

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<script>
function myFunction (R, C)                                            
{var myCod  = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="1">\n';
myCod += '<caption><b>Таблица ' + R + 'x' + C + '</b></caption>\n'; //заголовок с размерами
 for (var myCont = 1, j = 0; j < R; j++)                                 // строки
 {myCod += '<tr>';
    for (var k = 0; k < C; k++)  //столбцы
 { var SafPal = new Array ('00', '33', '66', '99', 'cc', 'ff');    
for (var clr = '#', q = 0; q < 3; q++) // цвет
clr += SafPal [Math.floor (Math.random () * SafPal.length)];  
myCod += '<td bgcolor="' + clr + '">' + (myCont++) + '</td>'    
       }                      //в ячейках - их номер
   myCod += '</tr>\n'; }
    myCod += '</table>\n';
var myNewWindow = window.open ('', '_blank');   
    myNewWindow.document.open ();
    myNewWindow.document.write (myCod);
    myNewWindow.document.close ();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form>
<p><tt> строки&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; - </tt><input name="myRows">  
<p><tt>столбцы - </tt><input name="myCells">          
<p><input type="button" value="Таблица"
onclick="myFunction (this.form.myRows.value, this.form.myCells.value)">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

***Примечание!*** Форматируйте свои вопросы. Это сильно увеличит Ваш шанс, получить ответ.

Для того что бы полностью войти в курс дела, советую поинтересоваться “***событиями движений***” в **JS**:
http://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-events
http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/intro

Приблизительное решение вашей задачи:

**CSS**:

```
.cols{
        display: inline-block; width: 180px; height: 180px; margin: 8px; 
        background: red; border: 1px solid black;
    }
.rows{
        padding: 5px; background: yellow; border-top: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
```

**HTML**:

```
<table style="margin: 0 auto; width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; border: none;">
   <tr class="rows" align="center">
       <td class="cols">1</td><td class="cols">2</td><td class="cols">3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="rows" align="center">
       <td class="cols">4</td><td class="cols">5</td><td class="cols">6</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="rows" align="center">
       <td class="cols">7</td><td class="cols">8</td><td class="cols">9</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**:

```
var cursorObj = document.body; //наш объект для отслежки курсора
var tds = cursorObj.getElementsByTagName("td"); //все TD в нашем cursorObj

var colors = new Array("red","blue","grey","green"); //массив цветов

//меняем расцветку из массива colors, для всех TD с классами cols
for(var i = 0; i<tds.length; i++){
  if(tds[i].getAttribute("class") == "cols"){
    tds[i].style.background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
  }
}

//отслеживаем курсор мышки над cursorObj
cursorObj.onmouseover = function(e){
    e = e || event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var tdParent = target.parentNode;

    //фильтруем объекты TD
    if(target.tagName == "TD"){

    //фильтруем объекты TD по цветам. В данном случае red(красный) и blue(синий)
    if(target.style.backgroundColor == "red" || target.style.backgroundColor == "blue"){
            target.onclick = function(){
                tdParent.removeChild(target); //удаляем текущий объект
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Готовый пример для анализа:
http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/9Sehg/2/